# Do the same rules apply to polynomial rings as to ring extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, quotient-spaces

Let $p$ be a prime and $g(x)$ irreducible $mod \ p$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. And let $d\ne 1 \ mod \ 4$ be a squarefree integer with $\omega:=\sqrt{d}$.

We know that $(p,g(\omega))$ is a prime ideal over $R:=\mathbb{Z[\omega]}$ and we want to figure out if $(p,g(\omega))$ is also a maximal ideal, which I tried to proof the following way:

\begin{equation}
R/((p,g(\omega))=\mathbb{Z[\omega]}/(p,g(\omega)) \cong \mathbb{Z_p[\omega]}/(g(\omega)) \cong \mathbb{Z_p}^{deg(g)}
\end{equation}

Hence $R/((p,g(\omega))$ is a field, which then implies that $((p,g(\omega))$ is a maximal ideal.

Is the last step of the isomorphisms a legit way to deal with $\mathbb{Z_p[\omega]}/(g(\omega))$ or does this idea only apply to $\mathbb{Z_p[x]}/(g(x)) \cong \mathbb{Z_p}^{deg(g)}$? 
And maybe another question: Is a polynomial ring just a special case of a ring extension?

Comment: In fact, when $d\not\equiv1\pmod4$, $\mathbb Z[\omega]$ is a ring of integers, which is a Dedekind ring, where every nonzero prime ideal is maximal. A polynomial ring is an infinite extension, and $R$ is a subring of $R[x]$.

Comment: Neither of your isomorphisms is true in general. It is the case the a polynomial ring is a kind of extension ring but they can behave quite differently than an algebraic extension.